# Save a list to a textfile c# in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to save the contents of a list (ObservableCollection) locally in a text file.

the whole thing is in WPF which had to be written without MVVM.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TimeRecorderPro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public DateTime startTime;
        public DateTime endTime;
        public Timer _currentTimer;

        public void Anfunk()
        {
            Timers.Add(_currentTimer);
            btnStart.Content = "Start";
        }

        void Löschen()
        {
            txtStart.Text = "";
            txtEnde.Text = "";
        }

        public void BemerkungEinfuegen(string str)
        {
            _currentTimer.Bemerkung = str;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Timer> Timers;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timers = new ObservableCollection<Timer>
            { };
            lstNames.ItemsSource = Timers;
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((string)btnStart.Content == "Start")
            {
                _currentTimer = new Timer();
                txtStart.Text = _currentTimer.Start.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                btnStart.Content = "Ende";
            }
            else
            {
                _currentTimer.Ende = DateTime.Now;
                txtEnde.Text = _currentTimer.Ende.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                _currentTimer.Dauer = _currentTimer.Ende - _currentTimer.Start;
            
                txtEnde.Text = _currentTimer.Ende.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

                Bemerkung bemerkungsdialog = new Bemerkung();
                bemerkungsdialog.Owner = this;
                bemerkungsdialog.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
                bemerkungsdialog.ShowDialog();
                /*
                Bemerkung bemerkungsdialog = new Bemerkung(_currentTimer);
                bemerkungsdialog.Owner = this;
                bemerkungsdialog.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
                bemerkungsdialog.ShowDialog();
                */

                Anfunk();
                Löschen();
             } 
        }
            
        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            string testtext = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/Zeitbuchung_" +      DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".txt";

            var objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(testtext);

            objWriter.WriteLine(Timers.ToString());
        }

        private void lstNames_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Timer
    {
        public Timer()
        {
            Start = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime Ende { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Dauer { get; set; }
        public string Bemerkung { get; set; }
    }
```

a new text file is created here, after that I thought the last loop iterate first, the outer loop iterates the items and the inner loop the clumns then to save the whole thing with the code in text file, I would be grateful for your answers like the code in this one Place had to look.

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    string testtext = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/Zeitbuchung_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".txt";

    var objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(testtext);

    objWriter.WriteLine(Timers.ToString());
}
```

XML Code

```
<Window
    x:Class="TimeRecorderPro.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeRecorderPro"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="200"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Closing="Window_Closing">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Form1"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblStart" Text="Start" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtStart" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblEnde" Text="Ende" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtEnde" />
            
            <Button
                x:Name="btnStart"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Width="100"
                Height="20"
                Margin="5,5,5,5"
                Click="btnStart_Click"
                Content="Start" />
           
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView
            x:Name="lstNames"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5,5,5,5" SelectionChanged="lstNames_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView x:Name="grdNames">
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="100"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Start}"
                        Header="Start" />
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="100"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ende}"
                        Header="Ende" />
                    <GridViewColumn
                        x:Name="sptDauer"
                        Width="100"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dauer}"
                        Header="Dauer" />
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="150"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bemerkung}"
                        Header="Bemerkung"/>
                 </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: you just can iterate over your `ObservableCollection` data and write to disk

Comment: Why do you want to save to a text file? Is this for persistence so you can load them back in again? If that is the case you might want to look at something like [JsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-5.0)

Comment: the tool is just a simple timer that saves the duration of activities locally in a text file as evidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;   

string filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Zeitbuchung_", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".txt");

File.WriteAllLines(filename, Timers.Select(x => $"Start={x.Start}, Ende={x.Ende}, Dauer={x.Dauer}, Bemerkung={x.Bemerkung}"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with a bit of a change in the code that you wrote worked very well, that's enough for now

Comment: Please accept this answer if it was helpful (click big tick mark), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you question is, but if you simply want so save you Timers as strings in a file, with each line representing a Timer, you could do it like this, I guess.

```cs
            string testtext = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/Zeitbuchung_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".txt";
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            foreach(Timer timer in Timers)
            {
                output.Add(timer.ToString());
            }
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(testtext, output);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                //do what ever you want here.
            }
```

You could also do it like this:

```
            string testtext = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/Zeitbuchung_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".txt";
            foreach (Timer timer in Timers)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.AppendAllLines(testtext, new List<string> { timer.ToString() });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //do what ever you want here.
                }
            }
```

But since we're talking about timers, which haven't been stopped when you're writing the file, I thought you want to save their states as fast as possible, to minimize deviations.